# How does the Higgs field relate to the Yang-Mills fields and gauge theories in general?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, higgs, yang-mills

I asked this in astronomy

> How does the Higgs field relate to the Yang-Mills fields and gauge
>   theories in general?

but they suggested I ask it here. It is very confusing. Is there an easy explanation that will tell me whether Higgs and gauge fields differ or what the difference is? and how they both relate to gauge field theories?

Comment: How what differ? How Higgs and Yang-Mills fields differ?

Comment: Yes what is the difference between them and how do they relate to gauge field theories?

Comment: Is there something specific e.g. the [Wikipedia article on the Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) does not cover that you wish to know?